# Struggling in pandas pivot tables and flattening them

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to recreate in python the following pivot table.
[image: pivot table sample]

In Excel, everything is working fine. 48 rows as expected x 68 columns. The values are the "count" for the items with those specific row/column.

In pandas, with the same data, I have a pivot table of 48 x 962 columns. Moreover, I've tried multiple ways to get a flattened dataframe (no multiindex), without success.

[raw csv here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincenzojrs/Personal/main/acqxcatxtempo.csv)

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(dataframe, 
                         index = 'customer_IDprovince', 
                         columns = 'category', 
                         aggfunc = len, 
                         fill_value = 0)
```

[image: python result]

Moreover, I tried to flatten it using *pivot to record*, *get level values*, *rename axis* and *reset index*. No way to make it flat. Could you help me, thanks.
Vincenzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aggfunc="size"` instead of `len`:

```py
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index="customer_IDprovince",
    columns="category",
    aggfunc="size",
    fill_value=0,
)

print(pivot.shape)
```

Prints:

```py
(48, 68)
```

Comment: and pivot_flat = pd.DataFrame(pivot.to_records()) to make it flat, works too. Thanks a lot, Andrej